# Trying to set preferred domain to https in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: seo, google

I am trying to set a preferred domain for `https://example.co.uk`. I have added and verified all four properties: `www.example.co.uk`, `example.co.uk`, `https://www.example.co.uk` and `https://example.co.uk`, but when i try to set the preferred domain to `https://www.example.co.uk` I can only find with www. and without www. so there's no https version showing.

I did the 301 redirect to https for all versions. Is this is sufficient or do I still need to set the preferred version to https?

Comment: It would help to know what you are working in, such as IIS on a Windows server (which version of both would help), your web host's management console, etc.  Someone may need to correct me on this, but if I remember right, you would need to make sure the bindings are set right in IIS to allow connections on HTTPs for that website.  I don't have enough experience to reliably post this as an answer though, but hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you're 301 redirecting all traffic from HTTP to HTTPS (and your site canonicals match) then that should be enough. Google Search Console doesn't have an option to set HTTPS as the preferred domain.